# RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 401

Tags: git, git-push

I have a git repository on a remote server. It's set up so I can push and pull to the repositories using https. I have a machine on which it works fine using my username and password. On a similar machine (both run the same Mac OS version), pulling works (but that's normal, pulling can be anonymous), but pushing results in:

```
 % git push
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1024 bytes | 1024.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 1), reused 6 (delta 1)
Password for 'https://ejetzer@ejetzer.ca': 
error: RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 401
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

The git version of the server is 2.27.0. The computer on which pushing and pulling works has git 2.24.0, and the one on which it doesn't work has git 2.23.0 or 2.24.3 (depending on the environment, I tried both).

The `.gitconfig`on both clients is the same:

```
[user]
    name = "Émile Jetzer"
    email = ...
[credential "..."]
    username = ejetzer
[credential]
    helper = cache
```

and the same repository `.git/config` file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = .../git/mesastar.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I checked the `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files on the server, and the username and password are fine on the machine for which it doesn't work. The server `.gitconfig` looks like this, based on the info on the host's [documentation](https://docs.webfaction.com/software/git.html):

```
[user]
    name = Émile Jetzer
    email = ...
[http]
    postBuffer = 157286400
    receivepack = true
    sslVerify = false
```

and the repo I'm cloning has the following `.git/config`

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
```

I have no idea why pushing doesn't work on the new machine, especially when it works on the old one.